# Clean install on AWS EC2 from GIT

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an app running on the AWS EC2 instance and something went wrong on the last update. I generally `ssh` to EC2 server and do a `git pull`, where I have a remote repository.

How can I do a clean install from my master repository?
Every time I do a git pull i get `you need to resolve your current index first`

Can I do a

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git pull
```

from the remote repo on the EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **definitely test this first in a non-production environment**, but yes, a hard `git reset` followed by `git pull` would do the trick.

According to the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset), `git reset --hard HEAD`, does:

> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded.

And then `git pull` will pull the latest changes from your remote and apply them to your EC2 instance ([documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)):

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch

So yes, if you run `git reset --hard HEAD` and then `git pull`, you'll wipe out any local untracked changes and then get the latest from the remote. In fact, if your EC2 has already pulled the most recent commit, you won't need to `git pull` at all.

However, again, can't stress enough: if this is a production server, please first investigate the untracked changes to be sure that there isn't anything important that you'll regret losing (`git status` and `git diff` will do) and then try the command, just to be sure, on a separate, non-production machine.

Comment: so i tried doing a 'git reset --hard HEAD' followed by  a'git pull', still no luck the site down

Comment: branch is upto date with 'origin/master' and a bunch of untracked files; nothing added to commit but untracked files present

Comment: ok - try this then: `git add :/; git reset --hard HEAD`. This will temporarily add the untracked files then delete them.

Comment: no luck, reverted my changes and did another git pull. The command seems to work fine but the site is not coming up. Is there anyway I can re install from EC2?

Comment: weird - then I would assume it's a non-git related issue. You could definitely try either a) deleting the entire site directory then cloning it again or b) launching a fresh EC2 instance and cloning into that. I would try (a) then (b) if you have to.

Comment: how do i delete the entire directory and clone again? and I am using a node.js app

Comment: sure. So assuming your app's folder is `app`, `cd` to the its parent directory (i.e. `cd ~` if your app is located at att `~/app`). Then, delete with `rm -rf app/`. Then, run `git clone REMOTE_URL`. You'll have to redo any local setup you may have done such as setting environment variables.

Comment: we are backup, we had some unresolved conflicts and had to hard delete them. Thank you so much for all your time and input!

Comment: fantastic! Congrats. If you need anything else that you can't find the answer to definitely open up another question. Also if you accept my answer that might be helpful for other users, up to you.